# Cannot convert from type x to type x?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function-pointers

When compiling (Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Express) this piece of code:

```
struct A
{
    template< typename T > static A Foo( void ) { return A(); }
    struct S
    {
        template< typename T > static S GetInstance( void )
        {
            S Result;
            Result.m_funcFoo = &A::Foo< T >;
            return Result;
        }
        A ( *m_funcFoo )( void );
    };
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A::S::GetInstance< int >();
}
```

I get a C2440 error:

> '=': cannot convert from 'A (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'A (__cdecl *)(void)'

That doesn't make sense to me. The two types named in the error text are obviously the same.
Also, when changing `Foo`'s return value to `int`, there is no such error.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT :**
So, if it's a bug, does anyone know how to solve this? Maybe by using casts? I need this code to compile...

Comment: At first, I thought that it's because `A (*)(void)` *is different* from `A (A::*)(void)`, but couldn't do it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a compiler bug.  VC++ is doing something very weird.

For example, this generates a very different error message:

```
struct A
{
    template< typename T > static struct A Foo( void ) { return A(); }
    struct S
    {
        template< typename T > static S GetInstance( void )
        {
            S Result;
            Result.m_funcFoo = &A::Foo< T >;
            return Result;
        }
        A ( *m_funcFoo )( void );
    };
};

sourceFile.cpp(5) : error C3856: 'A::Foo': class is not a class template
```

And this works:

```
struct X {};

struct A
{
    template< typename T > static X Foo( void ) { return X(); }
    struct S
    {
        template< typename T > static S GetInstance( void )
        {
            S Result;
            Result.m_funcFoo = &A::Foo< T >;
            return Result;
        }
        X ( *m_funcFoo )( void );
    };
};
```

Clearly it's getting confused by the name `A`, which should refer to the base class.

Adding a typedef didn't help, neither does a forward declaration of `struct A`, neither does qualifying the name as `::A` or `struct A`.

Oddly enough, VC++7 compiles it fine.

**Workaround:** Changing it like this:

```
struct A
{
    template< typename T > static A Foo( void ) { return A(); }

    struct S;
};

struct A::S
{
    template< typename T > static S GetInstance( void )
    {
        S Result;
        Result.m_funcFoo = &A::Foo< T >;
        return Result;
    }
    A ( *m_funcFoo )( void );
};
```

inverts the result, now VC++8 compiles ok and VC++7 generates the same error message.

I think there's a type identity issue between an incomplete type and the same type after completion.

All tests run using the [Dinkumware Multi-Compiler Test Tool](http://www.dinkumware.com/exam/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is a compiler bug or not, but at least it is documented on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).
I don't have a 2005 compiler at hand but vs2010 compiles your code if write it like this:

```
struct A
{
    template< typename T > static A Foo( void ) { return A(); }
    struct S
    {
        A ( *m_funcFoo )( void );       

        template< typename T > static S GetInstance( void );
    };
};

template< typename T > 
A::S A::S::GetInstance( void )
{
    S Result;
    Result.m_funcFoo = &A::Foo< T >;
    return Result;
}
```

Comment: @mkaes Did you actually instantiate `A::S::GetInstance` (for example by calling it)? I tested your code in both VS2005 and VS2010--it's still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug -- it compiles fine on Comeau (http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to track the problem down and now it seems like it isn't even necessary to have templated functions or nested structs to produce this strange error.

```
struct A
{
    typedef A ( * SimpleFuncPtr )( void );
    static void Foo( void )
    {
        SimpleFuncPtr func1 = 0;        // Ok.
        SimpleFuncPtr func2 = func1;    // Ok.
        A ( * func3 )( void ) = func1;  // C2440 on both VS2005 and VS2010
    }
};
```

By looking at the above piece of code it gets obvious that it is indeed a compiler bug (in my opinion).

Comment: The issue is with the incomplete type, and is described in the link provided by mkaes (i.e. because the type is incomplete at the time of the function pointer definition the compiler chooses a particular call convention that is later overriden when the full type is defined)